# How to run blender python script with args?

Tags: python

I have a python script that takes command-line args. I'm using it to create some blender objects. I'll run it from the command line (actually from a script on a server). I run it like this:

```
$BLENDER -b --python my-script.py -arg1 file1.in file2.in file3.out
```

... and the script runs fine, but I get a message saying "Error: File format is not supported in file file1.in" because presumably Blender is trying to read that file as a blend file.

So how can I prevent that? I just want blender to run my script. (Note that I'd be happy to just run it with python directly, but it seems to be difficult to load the `bpy` module without being in a running blender.)

This is on Blender 2.81 prerelease on Windows, btw. But I'll want it to run on Linux eventually.

Comment: Yup it's a duplicate as Robert says, but just so you know, it's listed under Misc Options in the [Command Line Manual Page](https://docs.blender.org/manual/en/latest/advanced/command_line/arguments.html)

Comment: The standard double-dash -- that'll work great. Thanks!